# How can I specify the working directory of the ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() to allow for relative paths in the -classpath option?

Tags: java

It appears as if a `JavaCompiler.CompilationTask` running from a

```
JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

runs with a working directory different from the one of the Java application invoking the task or alternatively relative paths passed to the classpath compiler option do not work.

How can I specify the working directory of the ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() to allow for relative paths in the -classpath option?

The code I am using is

```
        StandardJavaFileManager sjfm = javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        SpecialJavaFileManager fileManager = new SpecialJavaFileManager(sjfm, cl);

        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask compile = javac.getTask(out, fileManager, dianosticListener, options, classes, compilationUnits);
```

where `cl` is a class loader and options is an array of the two strings "-classpath" and a string being the (relative) classpath.

Comment: Based on your question I assume you know the alternative working directory you want to use. If that's the case, couldn't you just resolve the relative paths against it and then pass the results to the `-classpath` argument?

Comment: Yes, but that would be a bit cumbersome. I would like to "pass" the classpath of the running application (fetched from System.getProperty("java.class.path")) to the ToolProvider. I tried that, but it worked for absolute paths only. Converting relative paths to absolute paths may be possible, but not elegant.

Comment: It could be done with a very simple stream operation:     `Stream.of(System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator))
        .map(Path::of)
        .map(p -> p.isAbsolute() ? p : altDir.resolve(p))
        .map(Path::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(File.pathSeparator));`